# RuntimeError: Unable to initialize SecretService: Environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is unset

Tags: python, rhel, python-keyring

Running into issue with keyring:

RuntimeError: Unable to initialize SecretService: Environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is unset

SecretService is installed.
OS is RHEL

Running:

```
python -c "import keyring.backends.SecretService as SS; SS.Keyring.priority"
```

gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/secretstorage/__init__.py", line 41, in dbus_init
    return connect_and_authenticate()
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jeepney/integrate/blocking.py", line 70, in connect_and_authenticate
    bus_addr = get_bus(bus)
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jeepney/bus.py", line 53, in get_bus
    return find_session_bus()
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jeepney/bus.py", line 42, in find_session_bus
    addr = os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS']
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyring/backends/SecretService.py", line 37, in priority
    bus = secretstorage.dbus_init()
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/secretstorage/__init__.py", line 45, in dbus_init
    raise SecretServiceNotAvailableException(reason) from ex
secretstorage.exceptions.SecretServiceNotAvailableException: Environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is unset

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 26, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/home/webpage/.pyenv/versions/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyring/backends/SecretService.py", line 41, in priority
    "Unable to initialize SecretService: %s" % e)
RuntimeError: Unable to initialize SecretService: Environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is unset
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Missing dependency: dbus-python

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```sh
dbus-run-session -- python -c "import keyring.backends.SecretService as SS; SS.Keyring.priority"
```

SecretService (Gnome Keyring) needs a DBUS session. If you're running on a headless server, you'll need to run the app that needs access to keyring inside a dbus session (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my `.zshrc` was the only thing that ended up working for me:

```
export PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
```